# Health insurance for homeless woman?

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance

I'm trying to help a homeless woman in Saint Louis, Missouri get health insurance but do not know where to start? She has no income and no money at all but needs health insurance.  This woman has not paid any income taxes for at least 10 years.  Does anyone know where one would start in a situation like this?

I've never given healthcare a 2nd thought because I've always had health insurance through my employer. Please! Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Contact 211 in St Louis: http://www.211helps.org/

Comment: I don't have an answer here, but I'll add that there might be an organization that will help with meds and treatment for specific diseases/diagnoses.  If tax prove to be a requirement and this is time sensitive you may want to look for homeless and/or disease specific help.

Comment: Have you contacted a local homeless shelter?

Comment: No I have not contacted a homeless shelter.  Would a homeless shelter have advice, or counseling etc, about how to go about getting health insurance?

Comment: I would start [here](https://www.stlouis-mo.gov/government/departments/human-services/homeless-services/Homeless-Resources.cfm).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if my reply is helpful.  However, you may want to see if your state has some sort of Medicaid program for low-income/no-income residents.  From my research, it looks like Missouri has MO HealthNet.  Here: https://mydss.mo.gov/healthcare